# ST-LINK V2 USB driver WinUSB Access Denied

Tags: windows-7, usb, winusb, irp

I have a Win7/64 development machine configured (by someone else I can't contact) to develop/debug an embedded project using an ST-LINK/V2 dongle. The PC detects and installs the dongle Ok but no application can access the dongle, giving `'No ST-Link device detected'` type errors.

What makes this so frustrating is I have another Win7/64 machine that works flawlessly using identical driver, software and dongle and I haven't been able to transfer the dev environment between machines.

I've found (using USBlyzer) that WinUSB returns IRP Status `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` to each dongle access request. I'm hoping someone has seen something like this before.

P.S. "STMicroelectronics STLink dongle driver" is dated 28/07/2010.

Comment: Does the device show any problems in Device Manager on the failing machine?

Comment: No, the device is detected Ok

Comment: Do you have access to a hardware analyzer? It would be interesting to see if there is some difference in enumeration between the two machines. You are saying that the environments are the same, but there must be some difference between the systems that is causing the access denied behavior. Something else to try, which really shouldn't matter, is to run your application or IDE/debugger in Adminstrator mode on the failing machine.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not with the development software but the USB driver installed in the OS for the class of the ST-LINK/V2 dongle. The original installation installs a custom driver to support the dongle. Note that there is a different USB driver for Windows 8 and for Windows 7. STM has a site for the appropriate custom Windows drivers as well as firmware updates for the processor in the dongle, itself.